# multiple function almost the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

by any chance is there a way to short this code?
actually what it does is checking if a div (class) open, if so close it and each btn AKA (#go+A,B,C,D) goes to specific location on the HTML code

```
//--- Close & Go Home----//
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#go"),
        ProjShow = $(".content_projectA, .content_projectB, .content_projectC, .content_projectD, .content_projectE, .content_projectF, .content_projectG, .content_projectH, .content_projectI, .content_projectJ, .content_projectK, .content_projectL"),
        MyProjShow = ProjShow.hide();

    $("#go").on("click", function(){
        if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
        ProjShow.hide();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
        $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
        $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
        });
});
```

//--- Close & Go portfolio----//

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#goA"),
        ProjShow = $(".content_projectA, .content_projectB, .content_projectC, .content_projectD, .content_projectE, .content_projectF, .content_projectG, .content_projectH, .content_projectI, .content_projectJ, .content_projectK, .content_projectL"),
        MyProjShow = ProjShow.hide();  
    $("#goA").on("click", function(){
        if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
        ProjShow.hide();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
        $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
        $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
        });
});
```

//--- Close & Go About----//

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#goB"),
        ProjShow = $(".content_projectA, .content_projectB, .content_projectC, .content_projectD, .content_projectE, .content_projectF, .content_projectG, .content_projectH, .content_projectI, .content_projectJ, .content_projectK, .content_projectL"),
        MyProjShow = ProjShow.hide();

    $("#goB").on("click", function(){
        if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
        ProjShow.hide();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
        $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
        $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
        });
});
```

//--- Close & Go Skills----//

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#goC"),
        ProjShow = $(".content_projectA, .content_projectB, .content_projectC, .content_projectD, .content_projectE, .content_projectF, .content_projectG, .content_projectH, .content_projectI, .content_projectJ, .content_projectK, .content_projectL"),
        MyProjShow = ProjShow.hide();

    $("#goC").on("click", function(){
        if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
        ProjShow.hide();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
        $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
        $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
        });
});
```

//--- Close & Go contact----//

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#goD"),
        ProjShow = $(".content_projectA, .content_projectB, .content_projectC, .content_projectD, .content_projectE, .content_projectF, .content_projectG, .content_projectH, .content_projectI, .content_projectJ, .content_projectK, .content_projectL"),
        MyProjShow = ProjShow.hide();

    $("#goD").on("click", function(){
        if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
        ProjShow.hide();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
        $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
        $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: yes abstract all your similar code into a separate function then call this function within each of the click functions.

Comment: are these functions all on separate pages?

Comment: where are declared all this functions?

Comment: @royok, No its all in the same page different height location

Answer (score 0):

yes abstract all your similar code into a separate function then call this function within each of the click functions.   example:

```
function similar(){
    if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
        ProjShow.hide();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
        $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
        $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
        });
}
$("#goA").on("click", function(){
    similar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the code appears identical, just combine the selectors with a comma (which means match *any* of them):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#go, #goA, #goC, #goD"),
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the only difference is the element its being applied to each time. You could do the following:

```
function init(id){ 
    var MycloseNav = $("#" + id),
        ProjShow = $(".content_projectA, .content_projectB,     .content_projectC, .content_projectD, .content_projectE, .content_projectF, .content_projectG, .content_projectH, .content_projectI, .content_projectJ, .content_projectK, .content_projectL"),
        MyProjShow = ProjShow.hide();

    $("#" + id).on("click", function(){
        if (ProjShow == MyProjShow)
        {
            ProjShow.hide();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 200);
            $("#about, #skills, #contact, #footer").show();
            $("navA").hide();
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Then for each of the document ready functions have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    init("go");
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    init("goA");
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    init("goB");
});
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten out your code here are my suggestions:

1. Do not use .classA, .classB, .classC of you are not going to add individual css styles for them. Instead change it to a single css class.
   In this way you will not have to use

   `$('.classA, .classB, .classC').hide()`

   but just

   `$('.one-class').hide(); // All elements with class 'one-class' will be hidden`
2. You don't need to add id to each element if all you want to do is to hide the others and just show the selected/clicked one. Suppose you want to hide all `.close-nav` element except for the clicked one, use this code:

   ```
   $('.close-nav').click(function(){
       $('.close-nav').hide();
       $(this).show();

       // Other common code here
   });
   ```

Comment: it's impossible because each class contain different content